# Open file in intent by href without download

Tags: android, file, href, show

Any solution to open and show file in intent by href without download it?
In past I'm downloaded file via RxDownloader and after that only opening it

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I see no href.. I see no action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any solution to open and show file in intent by href without download it?

Use `ACTION_VIEW`, just as you would with local content.

Whether there is an app that handles the desired MIME type and an `https` (or whatever) scheme is up to the user and the developers of the user's installed apps. You do not have control over any of that.